# How to replace empty input field with a value

Tags: javascript, html, input

I would like to replace an empty input filed with the value "0" on the bottom of `on_click` without the new value "0" to be visible on the input filed.

```html
      <input type="number" id="myText"onfocus="if (this.value=!'') this.value='';" min="0" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)"/>
    <br/> <p  </p><input type="number" id="myletter"value="3" onfocus="if (this.value=!'') this.value='';" min="0" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)"/>
    <br/> <p <input  type="number" id="mycapitalletter" value="1" onfocus="if (this.value=!'') this.value='';" min="0" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)"/>       
    <br/> <p  <input  type="number" id="sc""value="0" onfocus="if (this.value=!'') this.value='';" min="0" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)"/>
    <br/>
       <br/>
       <button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
```

Comment: `<p <input` is invalid markup....., `<p  </p>` is invalid... etc

Comment: `id="sc""value="0" ` ... can you tell me what IDE or text/code editor you use?

Comment: `this.value=!''` should be `this.value!=='')`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan im using vs

Comment: You could use an <input type="hidden"> to store the hidden value?

Comment: Whatever IDE you use, if that doesn't show you that your code has countless severe syntactical problems, use a different IDE.

Comment: @Bargros but i want to the input to be "" every time the client taps on the input box and "0" for every input box that equals to "" on every time the Clint clicks the button

Comment: So for every input element if the element is equal `""` replace it with `"0"` whenever the user clicks on the element right?

Answer (score 0):

So basically all you need to do is fix `onfocus="if (this.value=!'') this.value='';` in all your input elements, mainly because you declared the equality operator incorrectly, you have `=!` instead of `!==` or `!=`. This is the fixed html:

```html
<input type="number" id="myText" onfocus="if (this.value!=='') this.value='';" min="0" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)" />
<br/>
<p> <input type="number" id="myletter" value="3" onfocus="if (this.value!=='') this.value='';" min="0" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)" /> </p>
<br/>
<p> <input type="number" id="mycapitalletter" value="1" onfocus="if (this.value!=='') this.value='';" min="0" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)" /> </p>
<br/>
<p> <input type="number" id="sc" value="0" onfocus="if (this.value!=='') this.value='';" min="0" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)" /> </p>
<br/>
<br/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
```

Or ultimately you can skip adding it manually to every single input and below the elements create your `<script> </script>` tag like so:

```html
<input type="number" id="myText" min="0" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)" />
<br/>
<p> <input type="number" id="myletter" value="3" min="0" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)" /> </p>
<br/>
<p> <input type="number" id="mycapitalletter" value="1" min="0" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)" /> </p>
<br/>
<p> <input type="number" id="sc" value="0" min="0" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)" /> </p>
<br/>
<br/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  inputs.forEach((input, i) => {
    input.onfocus = (event) => {
      event.currentTarget.value = "";
    }
  });
</script>
```

What the script does is as I said, loop through the HtmlCollection returned by the `querySelector`. Then attach a simple function which sets the value of the `input` to empty (or an empty string) to the `onfocus` event.

Comment: i dont know if the onfoucuse command confuse you, but i need the event (of the change from "" to 0) to happand onclick, and not onfoucse

Comment: Aaaaah I see what you mean, in that case what you can do is use the html `data-` directive and get the value with JQuery. I will update my post.

Comment: no i need the event to change evry "" to 0 and i want the event to happand onclick

Comment: Okay then all you have to do is change `event.currentTarget.value = "";` to `if(event.currentTarget.value==="") event.currentTarget.value = "0";`. But if what you're asking is if you can set a numeric value in its raw form as the input value then that is not possible, even if you try to set `event.currentTarget.value = 0` it'll be parsed onto a string, otherwise you need to parse the value onto a number in your `oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)"` should be `this.value = Math.abs(parseInt(this.value))"` or `this.value = Math.abs(Number(this.value))"`.